# Best way to execute avconv from php?

Tags: php, avconv

Best way to execute avconv from php?

```
system("avconv -i film.mkv")
or
exec("avconv -i film.mkv")?
```

somehow the result is NULL, while doing the same in console works fine, what is the best way to execute this command?

Comment: Text output is written to `stderr`.

Comment: @aergistal it returns null or 0 anyway even i write 2 > 1&